# MacBook Pro 2018 Battery not correctly working

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I have a problem with my MacBook Pro from December 2018. Yesterday the battery was fully charged when I shut it down and when I started it today it had 0 percent left. What could this mean? Is this a software error or is there a problem with the battery? What do you recommend to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing you should do is an [SMC Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).  After you’ve verified that your Mac is not holding a charge, you should take it in for service as it’s less than a year old

Comment: @Allan Thanks for your response! Currently the Macbook is working. I charged it to 100 percent and now is seems to act as usual so I'm a little bit afraid to do the SMC Reset. I did run the hardware diagnosis and it said that there are no problems. Would a battery problem have been listed in the hardware diagnosis?

Comment: A diagnostic quite possibly could give you some battery fault info.  No harm in running it.  An SMC reset is nothing “dangerous” as it only resets the SMC chip (handles power and fans) back to default.

Comment: @Allan I did the SMC reset and I'm currently not having problems at all. But before I did the SMC reset I encountered other problems which I will describe in another post.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, whats your version of MacOs ? If it's not the latest one then update, charge your mac for around 8hrs without using it. It fixed the bug for me, my mac was shutting down at 40% ~ and after those two things he was going low without a problem, hope it can help

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My version is 10.14.6. At the moment, my MacBook is working fine. Since I did the SMC reset the problems did not occur again. But I'll remember your instructions for the future!