# Strange problems with MBP (flickering Safari, popping noise, accent menu)

Tags: macbook-pro, safari

I already asked for help today in another posting: [MacBook Pro 2018 Battery not correctly working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359401/macbook-pro-2018-battery-not-correctly-working)

I don't know if this problem does relate to my new problem so I'm writing a new post.

My MacBook Pro from December 2018 has a strange problem: Sometimes when I'm searching things via Safari it suddenly shows (while entering the search words) the accent menu. Then it starts making a popping noise which does not stop. When I hover over the Apple symbol to shut down the Mac the items in the menu flicker. I can shut down the Mac and then everything seems to act normally for a while, but eventually it starts again. I reset the SMC and now it's acting normal.

Do you have any idea what could be the case with my MacBook? I have already searched in the internet but I could not find anything. What could I do?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I have a MacBook Pro 2018 with Touchbar. The current operating system is macOS Mojave Version 10.14.4. I did already run hardware diagnostics (pressed "D" while starting) and it said that there are no problems.

Comment: To clarify, this is a 2018 MacBook Pro? Also, it would be helpful to know what version of macOS you are using as well as whether or not you have run Apple Diagnostics (for hardware).

Comment: It’s entirely possible the two issues are related (I.e. possible swollen battery) or they may be coincidental.  If the SMC reset fixed it, keep any eye on the problem and see if it returns.  If it does, I would take it in to Apple for diagnostics

Comment: @Jake3231 I added the information to the posting. Do you have any idea what could be wrong with the MacBook?

Comment: @Allan Thanks! I think I will do this if no one else has already encountered the problem and knows what else one could do.